# How to query the filter the returned response by in Python using Flask API

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a task of Migrating all the `ASP.NET Web API` into `Pyhton API`. I am Using Flask with Blueprints to achieve that.

Right now I am struggling with `filtering` the returned results in my `Python API` (developed using Flask)

#### Here how I am doing it in `ASP.NET Web API`

```
query = String.Concat(queryMain, queryWhere, queryOrder, "  order by " + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy) ? " start_time " : orderBy + " " + orderType));
var ctx = new LairdDbContext();

        try
        {
            var anomalyList = ctx.AnomaliUinque.SqlQuery(query).ToList<AnomalyUnique>();
            if (anomalyList == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            Ag.Items = anomalyList.Where(x => x.rownumber >= startfrom && x.rownumber <= skp).ToList();
            Ag.Total = anomalyList.Count();
            return Ag;
        }
```

Notice I am getting the main results using 
`var anomalyList = ctx.AnomaliUinque.SqlQuery(query).ToList<AnomalyUnique>();`

And then I am filtering the returned results using the following line
`Ag.Items = anomalyList.Where(x => x.rownumber >= startfrom && x.rownumber <= skp).ToList();`

In the above line of code the `rownumber` is one of the columns in the returned by the `query`

#### Here is my `Python Flask API` Version [Which is Wrong since the query generated has syntax errors due to the 'WHERE rownumber' part]

```
query = querymain + queryWhere + queryOrder + ' order by ' + m_orderBy + ' WHERE rownumber >= {0} AND rownumber <= {1}'.format(startfrom,skp)
print(query)
try:
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    resp = jsonify(rows)
    resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    resp.status_code = 200
    print(resp)
    return resp
except Exception as e:

    print(e)
    return '', 400
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

#### Now My question is how do I replicate the same filter in Python using Flask API specifically the following line.

`anomalyList.Where(x => x.rownumber >= startfrom && x.rownumber <= skp).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` from the standard library

```py
filter(lambda x: x["rownumber"] >= startfrom && x["rownumber"] <= skp, resp)
```

Comment: Sorry, but should I do that on rows or Response ? And which part part do I send as response ?

Comment: I am Getting `'Response' object is not iterable`. Using it like following `try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        resp = jsonify(rows)
        res = filter(lambda x: x["rownumber"] >= startfrom and x["rownumber"] <= skp, resp)
        print(list(res))
        resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        resp.status_code = 200
        
        return resp
    except Exception as e:

        print(e)
        return '', 400
    finally:
        cursor.close()`